# MySQL Query fails via PHP PDO, succeeds through phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am building a query to return a tall/narrow table in a "wide" format (ends up being a CSV).

The Query i have come up with is as follows:

```
SELECT
  CONV(a.assetID, 10, 16) AS assetID,
  a.notes,
  a.budgetReplaceDate,
  p.propertyName AS property,
  b.buildingName AS building,
  MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS ?,
  MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS ?,
  MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS ?,
  MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS ?,
  MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, c.choice, NULL)) AS ?,
  MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS ?
FROM
  asset_details AS ad
  INNER JOIN assets AS a ON a.assetID = ad.assetID
  LEFT JOIN asset_choices AS c ON c.choiceID = ad.choiceID
  LEFT JOIN property AS p ON a.propertyID = p.propertyID
  LEFT JOIN property_buildings AS b ON a.buildingID = b.buildingID
WHERE
  a.clientID IN(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
  AND a.formID = ?
  AND (
    a.deletedID IS NULL
    OR a.deletedID = 0
  )
GROUP BY
  assetID
ORDER BY
  assetID
LIMIT
  10 OFFSET 0
```

And the parameters i am feeding it are as follows:

```
array(29) {
    [0]=> string(3) "385"
    [1]=> string(4) "f385"
    [2]=> string(3) "386"
    [3]=> string(4) "f386"
    [4]=> string(3) "387"
    [5]=> string(4) "f387"
    [6]=> string(3) "388"
    [7]=> string(4) "f388"
    [8]=> string(3) "389"
    [9]=> string(4) "f389"
    [10]=> string(3) "390"
    [11]=> string(4) "f390"
    [12]=> string(2) "14"
    [13]=> string(2) "15"
    [14]=> string(2) "26"
    [15]=> string(2) "29"
    [16]=> string(2) "30"
    [17]=> string(2) "31"
    [18]=> string(2) "32"
    [19]=> string(2) "34"
    [20]=> string(2) "35"
    [21]=> string(2) "36"
    [22]=> string(2) "37"
    [23]=> string(2) "38"
    [24]=> string(2) "39"
    [25]=> string(2) "40"
    [26]=> string(2) "41"
    [27]=> string(2) "42"
    [28]=> string(2) "41"
}
```

I am getting the following error when trying to execute it via PDO in PHP:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CONV(a.assetID, 10, 16) AS assetID, a.notes, a.budgetReplaceDate, ' at line 1 in report.php on line 580

If i go and manually copy and paste each of the values in the array into the correct place in the query and run it via phpMyAdmin(or adminer) it works correctly.

I thought it may be this part:

```
  MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS ?,
  MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS ?,
  MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS ?,
  MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS ?,
  MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, c.choice, NULL)) AS ?,
  MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS ?
```

but have a simplified version of the query working just fine with that. I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on. What am i missing?

Below is the general log:

```
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
2019-04-11T08:54:26.499114Z 376072 Connect  *USERNAME*@localhost on *DATABASE* using TCP/IP
2019-04-11T08:54:26.499374Z 376072 Query    SELECT sessionID, uid, loginDate, lastActive, ipAddress FROM session WHERE loggedOut = 0 AND token = '*REDACTED*' AND lastActive >= '2019-04-10 15:54:26' - INTERVAL 27 HOUR
2019-04-11T08:54:26.499889Z 376073 Connect  *USERNAME*@localhost on *DATABASE* using TCP/IP
2019-04-11T08:54:26.500007Z 376073 Query    SELECT userID, userEmail, userLevel, userGroupID, joinDate, firstname, lastname, subscriptionEndDate, contactNo, contractorID, homePropertyID, timezone, uuid FROM users WHERE userID = '2'
2019-04-11T08:54:26.500487Z 376074 Connect  *USERNAME*@localhost on *DATABASE* using TCP/IP
2019-04-11T08:54:26.500595Z 376074 Query    SELECT * FROM userGroups WHERE userGroupID = '1'
2019-04-11T08:54:26.500891Z 376073 Query    SELECT ClientID FROM client
2019-04-11T08:54:26.501095Z 376073 Quit 
2019-04-11T08:54:26.501180Z 376072 Query    UPDATE session SET lastActive = '2019-04-11 18:54:26', browser = NULL WHERE sessionID = '2691'
2019-04-11T08:54:26.503173Z 376074 Query    SELECT * FROM markers
2019-04-11T08:54:26.503416Z 376072 Quit 
2019-04-11T08:54:26.503954Z 376074 Query    SELECT f.formID, f.formName, f.formTable, f.category, f.budget, s.formName AS srvcName, s.formID AS srvcFormID, s.formTable AS srvcTable, s.srvcFreq AS freq FROM forms as f
            LEFT JOIN srvcForms AS s ON f.formID = s.assetTable WHERE f.formID = '41' LIMIT 1
2019-04-11T08:54:26.504237Z 376074 Query    SELECT * FROM formField WHERE formID = '41' ORDER BY position, fieldID
2019-04-11T08:54:26.504948Z 376074 Query    SELECT 
    CONV(a.assetID, 10, 16) AS assetID,
    a.notes,
    a.budgetReplaceDate,
    p.propertyName AS property,
    b.buildingName AS building
    ,
    MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = '385', ad.text, NULL)) AS 'f385',
    MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = '386', ad.text, NULL)) AS 'f386',
    MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = '387', ad.text, NULL)) AS 'f387',
    MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = '388', ad.text, NULL)) AS 'f388',
    MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = '389', c.choice, NULL)) AS 'f389',
    MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = '390', ad.text, NULL)) AS 'f390'
FROM asset_details AS ad
INNER JOIN assets AS a ON a.assetID = ad.assetID
LEFT JOIN asset_choices AS c ON c.choiceID = ad.choiceID
LEFT JOIN property AS p ON a.propertyID = p.propertyID
LEFT JOIN property_buildings AS b ON a.buildingID = b.buildingID

WHERE a.clientID IN('14', '15', '26', '29', '30', '31', '32', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42') AND a.formID = '41' AND (a.deletedID IS NULL OR a.deletedID = 0)
GROUP BY assetID ORDER BY assetID LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
2019-04-11T08:54:26.512918Z 376074 Quit 
2019-04-11T08:54:32.938734Z 376067 Query    set global general_log = "OFF"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was actually working, it was an error further down.

I am rewriting an existing function and did not notice the function reused the SQL query further down to perform a count of total records (to show "Viewing 1-10 of 1000"). the error was actually with that and was a quick easy fix.

Lesson learned, ACTUALLY CHECK THE LINE NUMBER THE ERROR IS ON!

To be fair, I did have a couple of typo's up top to start with, just didn't notice when the line number changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `?` placeholders to specify the alias of a column in a MySQL prepared statement.  So, you should just use hard-coded alias names:

```
SELECT
    CONV(a.assetID, 10, 16) AS assetID,
    a.notes,
    a.budgetReplaceDate,
    p.propertyName AS property,
    b.buildingName AS building,
    MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS max_one,
    MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS max_two,
    MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS max_three,
    MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS max_four,
    MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, c.choice, NULL)) AS max_five,
    MAX(IF(ad.fieldID = ?, ad.text, NULL)) AS max_six
  FROM asset_details AS ad
  -- the rest of your query the same
```

But, I see no good reason to control the aliases as you have in mind.  Your PHP script also would probably need a hard-coded already known alias name in order to extract the value.

Comment: It does work, If you read the question i have already stated that I have tested that and it works.

I am unable to hard code the values as they are stored in a database, Think of it as a survey system, the surveys all have wildly diffrent questions in them and they have to be created from a frontend, so hard coding wont work. this seems the be the safest (sql injection wise) way of achieving this.

this query is generated, sometimes there may only be 1 of the MAX(IF) sections, sometimes there could be 30.

Comment: There isn't really a safe way to do this, at least prepared statements can't really help here.  You would have to concatenate in those dynamic aliases, and before hand you would have to sterilize the inputs; that's a lot of work to do something which probably isn't necessary.  I suggest rethinking your original premise here.

Comment: How is the way i'm doing it not safe?

Comment: Read about SQL injection.  Again, you _can't_ bind alias names using placeholders.

Comment: Then how come in my testing i have done the EXACT same thing and it works?

Comment: Anyway, I have tested it your way (by doing it the unsafe way and using a loop to hard code the alias name's) and i am still getting the exact same error.

Comment: Apologies if my answer does not completely resolve your problem.  I have pointed out the flaws in your original query which I was able to see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191887/discussion-between-mike16889-and-tim-biegeleisen).